# Handsontable Special Currency Format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I am using Angular with handsontable to create an editable table.

I need to format my table for all number fields to look like this

```
1,000.00 USD
```

and of course USD is not fixed its actually read from an API.

I have tried a format to be "0,0.00 USD" and "0,0.00 USD"

And all I have found is a way to use it via $ and enable language or culture variable which is not a valid answer.

Comment: Have you tried `filter: currency` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add angular `filter`

```
<tr>
   <td>{{amount | currency:"USD$"}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or you can use

```
<tr>
   <td>{{amount | currency }}</td>
</tr>
```

**amount** should be anything

Or you can refer [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Comment: if you are using angularJs then you can use that filter. Have you included angularJs file in index page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this type, you can use this code. Only change this line
 `format: '0,0.00'`

```
data: "gt_base",
type: 'text',
format: '0,0.00',
```